# What is $g$ for a bob hanging from a string?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, acceleration, string

Imagine a bob hanging from a string. Now, let's say that you pull the string to the right (or left, doesn't matter), and then allow it to fall freely. Will the gravitational acceleration ***g*** be the same to the ***g*** if there was **no string attached** (*pun intended (if u know what the pun is)*)? If so, then how? Shouldn't the upward pull of the string (aka **tension**) affect it somehow?

Comment: Is the string also falling?

Comment: $g$ will be the same but the acceleration of the body will not be $g$ if the string is deflected from the vertical and it's moving

Comment: no the string is fixed to the ceiling

Answer (score 2):

The force on a mass $m$ in a gravitational field $\vec g$ is $m\vec g$.

A mass $m$ subjected to such a force and only that force will have an acceleration $a$ which can be found by using Newton’s second law, $m\vec g = m \vec a \Rightarrow \vec a = \vec g$.
In other situations when a mass has other forces acting on it in addition to the gravitational force the mass will not  have an acceleration equal to $\vec g$ but the gravitational force on it will still be $m\vec g$.

In part your query is probably due the use of the term acceleration due to gravity (and using the unit $\rm m\,s^{-2}$) rather than the term gravitational field strength (and using the unit $\rm N\,kg^{-1}$).

Comment: sorry I was asking about *a* not *g*. That was my mistake. So, What's the *a* in my question( aka the net acceleration)?

Comment: The acceleration of the mass can be though of as having two components one at a tangent to its trajectory produced by the component of the weight in that direction and the  other being perpendicular to the trajectory and pointing to the pivot produced by the vector sum of the tension in the string and the component of the weight perpendicular to the trajectory.

Comment: [Diagram](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcourses.lumenlearning.com%2Fsuny-osuniversityphysics%2Fchapter%2F15-4-pendulums%2F&psig=AOvVaw2r3_LoS6ZU_1f4TKFs-_rU&ust=1634832091134000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAsQjRxqFwoTCLi6vKKu2fMCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD)